# Delete contents of selected columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an excel file that I am manually deleting contents of entire column that are not in sequential order. This requires a lot of manual work as some rows contain blank values in the column. So, I am trying to write VBA script to remove the contents of selected columns except the first row (header)

I've been googling and reading stack overflow articles so far... and this is what I accomplished (something worked...) so far

```
Sub clear_contents()
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String
ActiveSheet.Columns("D").Delete

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
  columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
  If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
           "0cc17562-08c1-4f99-a234-ce6fa0cc5be4", vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

What this script is doing is deleting the columns with specified header value. 
This is close.. but not really what I am trying to do

1. I'd like to select columns without typing header name.. like select column C, D, G , F then delete.
2. Also, I still need to keep columns with header. This script completely removes the entire column..

I am a noob to VBA, so I do need a lot of help here!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understood your request, you don't need `.Delete` function, just `.ClearContents`. This macro loops through every selected column (doesn't matter if you select whole columns or just several rows from each), finds last occupied row, and then clear everything that is between second and last row, so headers in first row will stay untouched.

```
Sub clear_contents()
Dim Col As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sel As Range, rng As Range

Set Sel = Selection
For Each rng In Sel.Columns
    Col = rng.Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < 2 Then LastRow = 2
    Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col)).ClearContents
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This works to remove contetns! But can you help me understand how to select specific columns? how should I define selection/range?

Comment: Just select it in your sheet and run the macro. The range of columns is dependent on actual selection.

Comment: got it! this works perfect. Thanks a lot for the help!!